# Join in pandas using columns as rows

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

I am trying to join these two pandas dataframes on the column sample so that 'total_reads' corresponds to the correct value for that column from the second df.

| sample | Downsample | Series | total_reads |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ERR4223677 | Down_10 | ERP120397 | 2500121 |
| ERR4225180 | Down_50 | ERP120397 | 12500608 |  |  |  |
| ERR4225239 | Down_50 | ERP120397 | 22190433 |  |  |  |
| ERR4225273 | Down_75 | ERP120397 | 18750912 |  |  |  |
| ERR4225325 | Raw_Data | ERP120397 | 25001217 |  |  |  |
| ERR4225370 | Down_25 | ERP120397 | 11095216 |  |  |  |
| ERR4225386 | Down_75 | ERP120397 | 33285650 |  |  |  |
| ERR4225387 | Raw_Data | ERP120397 | 44380867 |  |  |  |

and

| series | sample | Raw_Data | Down_75 | Down_50 | Down_25 | Down_10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ERP120397 | ERR4223677 | 762828 | 666093 | 534468 | 342070 | 177346 |  |
| ERP120397 | ERR4225180 | 1304291 | 1085140 | 816593 | 467548 | 206039 |  |
| ERP120397 | ERR4225239 | 1007582 | 857346 | 664345 | 394410 | 180437 |  |
| ERP120397 | ERR4225273 | 872706 | 750629 | 592641 | 362647 | 172176 |  |
| ERP120397 | ERR4225325 | 1052892 | 900727 | 701227 | 420112 | 187159 |  |
| ERP120397 | ERR4225370 | 913854 | 771552 | 590478 | 347846 | 159422 |  |
| ERP120397 | ERR4225386 | 1174005 | 995511 | 767682 | 455647 | 204522 |  |  |  |  |

Comment: All right, good luck! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: total_reads from Down_10 are in a column next to Down_10 from the second dataframe

Comment: What column it the second dataframe are you speaking about? Do you want to get joint rows where df1["total_reads"]==df2["Raw_Data"], with join on sample?

Comment: Note that in the first data frame you have "Sample" and in the other "sample". Column names are case-sensitive.

Comment: I am trying to merge these two dataframes on sample and where Down_50 in the second df is equal to Down_50 (column name) in the first df. Does that help?

Comment: yes, that's the join I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can `pivot` and `merge`:

```
(df2.merge(df1.pivot(['Series', 'Sample'], 'Downsample', 'total_reads').add_suffix('_total'),
           left_on=['series', 'sample'], right_index=True)
    .sort_index(axis=1)
)
```

output:

```
   Down_10  Down_10_total  Down_25  Down_25_total  Down_50  Down_50_total  \
0   177346      2500121.0   342070            NaN   534468            NaN   
1   206039            NaN   467548            NaN   816593     12500608.0   
2   180437            NaN   394410            NaN   664345     22190433.0   
3   172176            NaN   362647            NaN   592641            NaN   
4   187159            NaN   420112            NaN   701227            NaN   
5   159422            NaN   347846     11095216.0   590478            NaN   
6   204522            NaN   455647            NaN   767682            NaN   

   Down_75  Down_75_total  Raw_Data  Raw_Data_total      sample     series  
0   666093            NaN    762828             NaN  ERR4223677  ERP120397  
1  1085140            NaN   1304291             NaN  ERR4225180  ERP120397  
2   857346            NaN   1007582             NaN  ERR4225239  ERP120397  
3   750629     18750912.0    872706             NaN  ERR4225273  ERP120397  
4   900727            NaN   1052892      25001217.0  ERR4225325  ERP120397  
5   771552            NaN    913854             NaN  ERR4225370  ERP120397  
6   995511     33285650.0   1174005             NaN  ERR4225386  ERP120397
```

###### alternative with `join`

```
(df2
 .set_index(['series', 'sample']).rename_axis(['Series', 'Sample'])
 .join(df1.pivot(['Series', 'Sample'], 'Downsample', 'total_reads').add_suffix('_total'))
 .sort_index(axis=1)
 .reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
      Series      Sample  Down_10  Down_10_total  Down_25  Down_25_total  \
0  ERP120397  ERR4223677   177346      2500121.0   342070            NaN   
1  ERP120397  ERR4225180   206039            NaN   467548            NaN   
2  ERP120397  ERR4225239   180437            NaN   394410            NaN   
3  ERP120397  ERR4225273   172176            NaN   362647            NaN   
4  ERP120397  ERR4225325   187159            NaN   420112            NaN   
5  ERP120397  ERR4225370   159422            NaN   347846     11095216.0   
6  ERP120397  ERR4225386   204522            NaN   455647            NaN   

   Down_50  Down_50_total  Down_75  Down_75_total  Raw_Data  Raw_Data_total  
0   534468            NaN   666093            NaN    762828             NaN  
1   816593     12500608.0  1085140            NaN   1304291             NaN  
2   664345     22190433.0   857346            NaN   1007582             NaN  
3   592641            NaN   750629     18750912.0    872706             NaN  
4   701227            NaN   900727            NaN   1052892      25001217.0  
5   590478            NaN   771552            NaN    913854             NaN  
6   767682            NaN   995511     33285650.0   1174005             NaN
```

Comment: I'm getting NaNs in both when I run it on my dataframe

Comment: @spaceghost are your dataframes different from those shown in the question? Can you provide them as DataFrame constructor or dictionary for clarity?